# perl - filter hash by keys matching regex without smartmatch

Tags: regex, perl, hash, grep

I need to filter a hash based on a regex, deleting the keys from the hash if the regex matches.

This is what i got so far, unfortunately it doesnt do anything and i have no clue why.

So, i am building the regex out of an array of strings, i need to match substrings as well, so if the hash key is `someprefix_somestring` i need to match it against `somestring` or `string`

```
my $hashref = {someprefix_somekey => 'somevalue', otherprefix_otherkey => 23, otherprefix_somekey => 'someothervalue'};
my @array_of_strings = ('somekey', 'strings', 'bits', 'bobs');

my $regex = join( '|', sort { length( $b ) <=> length( $a ) or $a cmp $b } @array_of_strings );
$regex    = qr{($regex)};

delete $hashref->{ grep { !m/$regex/ } keys %$hashref };
```

I would expect `$hashref` to look like this afterwards: `{otherprefix_otherkey => 23}` since `someprefix_somekey` and `otherprefix_somekey` would have matched `$regex` and would therefore be deleted from the hash

I have no clue why this is not working, please enlighten me

Thanks to hobbs answer i was able to make it work, this is what i have now:

```
my $hashref = {someprefix_somekey => 'somevalue', otherprefix_otherkey => 23, otherprefix_somekey => 'someothervalue'};
my @array_of_strings = ('somekey', 'strings', 'bits', 'bobs');

my $regex = join( '|', sort { length( $b ) <=> length( $a ) or $a cmp $b } @array_of_strings );
$regex    = qr{($regex)};

delete @{$hashref}{grep { m/$regex/ } keys %$hashref };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `delete` isn't quite right because you're using the notation to access a single key, therefore the `grep` is run in scalar context. Which means that ultimately you're trying to do something like `delete $hashref->{'3'}` if there are three keys not matching your regex.

If you change your last line to this it should work:

```
delete @{$hashref}{grep /$regex/, keys %$hashref };
```

which uses a hash slice. If you think that syntax is too ugly, you could also

```
delete $hashref->{$_} for grep /$regex/, keys %$hashref;
```

which might read a little bit more naturally.

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants to keep only what doesn't match, so you should delete all entries that grep can find, without the `!`.

Comment: Hash slices are an underappreciated tool in perl.

Comment: Slices should only be used for simple things. Sooner or later some maintainer will replace the above code with a foreach loop. Write your code so it can be easily maintained. "Don't be clever," Damian Conway, Perl Best Practices http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/perl-best-practices/appendix-b.html